# Method- taking two double parameters, and returning an integer value using a method

Tags: methods

I am having trouble writing a method. I need to write it to take two double parameters, and return an integer value

public class MyClass {

public static void sizeOfRange (  )  {

}

}

//This is all I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at name of the function, i guess you are looking for something like:

```
public static int sizeOfRange(double start, double end) {
     return Math.abs((int)(end - start)) + 1;
}
```